# SQLAlchemy oracle connect

Tags: python, oracle, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Most of the connections I see don't resemble the type of SQLAlchemy connection I am using. I am wondering if there is a way of mirroring this style or if it has to be used within create_engine.  Here is an example of my connection and a class of I am using to connect to a specific table:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Api
from flask_cors import CORS
from flask_jwt_extended import JWTManager
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv(verbose=True)

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = os.getenv('SECRET_KEY')
app.config['JWT_SECRET_KEY'] = os.getenv('SECRET_KEY')
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = os.getenv('SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI')
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
app.config['JWT_BLACKLIST_ENABLED'] = True
app.config['JWT_BLACKLIST_TOKEN_CHECKS'] = ['access', 'refresh']
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
api = Api(app)
jwt = JWTManager(app)
```

My DB URI string looks like this:

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI="oracle+cx_oracle://username:password@db_url/dbName"
```

This is stored in an environment variable and I don't use string formatting to fill in those portions of username, password, etc (I have them hard coded I just removed them for security reasons)

And now the class I am trying to create the connection with:

```
from App import db


class EventModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE_NAME'

    RC_ID = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    PRODUCT_ID = db.Column(db.Integer)
    RELEASE_ID = db.Column(db.Integer)
    RCPM_ID = db.Column(db.Integer)
    FIT_DTTM = db.Column(db.String(25))
    DATACTR_ID = db.Column(db.String(10))
    COMMENT_TXT = db.Column(db.String(500))
    DESCR_TXT = db.Column(db.String(300))
    EVENTCMPLT_FLG = db.Column(db.String(1))
    EVENTCMPLTONTM_FLG = db.Column(db.String(1))
    ATTACHMENTS_FLG = db.Column(db.String(1))
    UUID = db.Column(db.Integer)
    URLS = db.Column(db.String(4000))
```

again the table portion I renamed for security reasons.

I attempted to attach the schema name also to the DB URI I store in my environment variable. I always get this error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.DatabaseError: (cx_Oracle.DatabaseError) ORA-12505: TNS:listener does not currently know of
        SID given in connect descriptor
```

I appreciate everyone's assistance. I normally work with postgres and the project I am converting my normal method to is using an oracle db.

Comment: The schema is NOT a part of the connection string. It defaults to the username used to connect to the database. If you want to use another schema, you have to either create synonyms for it's objects, or if you like to use env vars, put it in a separate env var, and read it like you did for the others: getenv....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for your help. I forgot to post this and I can't remember where I found this, but this is how I solved the issue:

```
oracle_connection_string = 'oracle+cx_oracle://{username}:{password}@' + 
cx_Oracle.makedsn('{hostname}', '{port}', service_name='{service_name}')

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = oracle_connection_string.format(
  username=db_user,
  password=db_pw,
  hostname=db_host.split(':')[0],
  port='1521',
  service_name=db
)
```

Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `<tns alias>` of your database at the end of the `SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI` string converted to

`engine = db.create_engine('oracle+cx_oracle://username:password@mydb')`

where `mydb` is assumed to be `<tns alias>` within your `TNSNAMES.ORA` file such as

```
mydb=
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = proddb1)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = mycompany.com)
    )
  )
```

Comment: @user2112618 if you are unfamiliar with tnsnames.ora files, info about where to put them is in the [cx_Oracle documentation](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/connection_handling.html#optional-oracle-net-configuration-files).